# Having troubles with edit mode high poly meshes in 2.90

Tags: edit-mode

Recently updated to version 2.90 after using 2.79 for several years to get a performance increase, since I've been working with higher poly meshes and blender isnt coming close to using all the resources available to it.
The New version? Great performance increase! Though using edit mode with the high poly meshes is a nightmare. I may be missing some setting... but when I'm in transparent wireframe in edit mode the vertices I'm selecting are completely obscured by the surrounding mesh! I tried everything I could find online to changing theme colors and vertices px size but I still cant get it to function like 2.79.

Everything is just so clear in 2.79... see picture for what I mean. Both pictures have the exact same areas selected.
[image: comparison]

If there is something I am missing or that's just how it is please let me know ;m;